# Permalinks for thumbs with get_post_gallery

Tags: permalinks

On attachment page I would like to display all images belonging to the parent post, so there should a thumbnail gallery. Using...

```
$parent = get_post_field( 'post_parent', get_the_ID() );
$gallery = get_post_gallery( $parent, false );
```

...gives this which is kinda weird to use. Why are ids seperatated from src? 
How do I even get ID of that thumbnail to get the permalink? Even If I get this working by some complicated core, it feels dirty. Isn't there a better solution?

```
array (size=3)
  'columns' => string '4' (length=1)
  'ids' => string '8844,8853,8498,8845,8846,8847,8848,8849,8852,8854,8843,8851,8855,8499,9672,9673' (length=79)
  'src' => 
    array (size=16)
      0 => string 'http://localhost/biljke/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/uljana-repica-251-200x200.jpg' (length=80)
      1 => string 'http://localhost/biljke/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/uljana-repica-33-200x200.jpg' (length=79)
      2 => string 'http://localhost/biljke/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/uljana-repica-13-200x200.jpg' (length=79)
      3 => string 'http://localhost/biljke/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/uljana-repica-26-200x200.jpg' (length=79)
```

I need something like this

```
<?php foreach($gallery as $img) : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($img->ID); ?>">
        <img  src="<?php echo $img->src ?>" alt=" -<?php echo $img->title " />
    </a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

There is also `get_post_gallery_images()` but it returns only thumbnail urls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split the [get_post_gallery](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_gallery) `ids` string into an array before you can loop through it.

```
$parent = get_post_field( 'post_parent', get_the_ID() );

$gallery = get_post_gallery($parent, false);

$ids = explode(',', $gallery[ 'ids' ]);

foreach($ids as $attachment_id) {
$img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_url($attachment_id, 'medium');
$img_srcset = wp_get_attachment_image_srcset($attachment_id, 'medium');
$title = get_the_title($attachment_id);
?>
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($attachment_id); ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo esc_url($img_src); ?>"
         srcset="<?php echo esc_attr($img_srcset); ?>"
         sizes="auto" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($title); ?>"></a>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second argument you are passing to [`get_post_gallery()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_gallery) is instructing the function to dump the raw data. Without that argument the function will generate HTML for the gallery similar to what you are asking for though not exactly the same. For all practical purposes that shouldn't matter.